# .NET frameworks not showing in visual studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm not able to find any when trying to create a new project in visual Studio 2015. I've .NET Frameworks 4.5, 4.6 & 4.7 installed. it still doesn't populate in the list of frameworks. Can someone please help on how to troubleshoot this?

[image: .NET framework]

Comment: Which version vs 2015 (community, express, professional, ulitmate)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot select Target Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279515/cannot-select-target-framework-4-5-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: re-installed vs2015, available frameworks are now showing up..Thanks all for your help.