# Unable to select .Net version and create project in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed new version of Visual studio 2015. When I try to create new project in visual studio, the Target dropdown list is empty and 'Ok' button is disabled. 
[image]

I've uninstalled it and installed again but still getting the same issue. Any suggestion or help ?

Comment: Can you Right click on project >> Properties,  and change the target version?

Comment: there is not way to create new project. Target version is empty and ok button disable

Comment: [repair VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42301633/1466046) via controlpanel

Comment: Actually, I am using both VS 2017 and VS 2015. I repired from Control Panel, but still not working